# GruntJs:how to bypass a task in grunt build process

Tags: gruntjs

is there a way to bypass the task in the grunt build process using options??
In below example i want to bypass the test and do only package and buildArtifacts tasks.

Example:

```
     grunt.registerTask('test', [  
        'karma:continuous' ,     
      'e2e-test'
    ]);

     grunt.registerTask('build', function (target) { 

      grunt.task.run(['force:on','package','test','force:off','buildArtifacts']);
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

Afterall its a .js file, i think you can write a custom js function to edit what you want to run based on "option"

Answer (score 1):

As earlier said, you can edit the Gruntfile.js to create a new task.

```
grunt.registerTask('build-bypass-test', ['package','buildArtifacts']);
```

On command link just execute the below command.

```
grunt build-bypass-test
```

**Updated Answer**

```
var test = grunt.option('test');

grunt.registerTask('build',function() {
    if(test) {
        grunt.log.writeln('Running without test');
        grunt.task.run(['force:on','package','force:off','buildArtifacts']);
    } else {
        grunt.log.writeln('Running with test');
        grunt.task.run(['force:on','package','test','force:off','buildArtifacts']);
    }

});
```

Hope this helps you. :)

Comment: i want to use same task 'build' but pass on options like grunt build --test which excludes the test task from build.I am not sure if this can be acheived using grunt.option???